# Jenkins - can't see "Manage Jenkins" option

Tags: jenkins

I've just installed the latest version of Jenkins and enabled the **so-called "Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy"**.

I have added a few users with all privileges and some of them can see the **"Manage Jenkins"** option after logging into Jenkins, but there are people who can log in but can't see this option.

Really strange behavior. I have checked the configuration in jenkins.xml but it seems ok. Do you have any idea what can be an issue?

Thank you for any suggestions,
Foxrafi

Comment: this is an issue with LDAP authentication.

Answer (score 4):

Try using the link **https://<JENKINS_URL>:8080/manage** loaded the **Manage Jenkins** option on the UI.

OS: **CentOS**

Java Version: **1.8**

Answer (score 2):

It seems the permissions in `config.xml` are case-sensitive. So when there is  such an entry :

```
<permission>hudson.model.Item.Build:mysuperuserlogin</permission>
```

and you log using LDAP authentication and this variant of password MySuperUserLogin, you will be able to log in successfully but you won't be able to use the permission.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `authorizationStrategy` has been updated

**Step 1:** Go to your **config.xml** file and open this to any editor

```
sudo vim /var/lib/jenkins/config.xml
```

**Step 2:** Search **authorizationStrategy** tag inside xml file and change the value to

```
<authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy">
```

**Step 3:** Restart Jenkins:

```
sudo systemctl restart jenkins
```

Try to log in now!

**Here is the default xml file of Jenkins you can crosscheck your other configurations**

```
<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hudson>
  <disabledAdministrativeMonitors/>
  <version>2.277.2</version>
  <numExecutors>2</numExecutors>
  <mode>NORMAL</mode>
  <useSecurity>true</useSecurity>
  <authorizationStrategy class="hudson.security.FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy">
    <denyAnonymousReadAccess>false</denyAnonymousReadAccess>
  </authorizationStrategy>
  <securityRealm class="hudson.security.HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm">
    <disableSignup>true</disableSignup>
    <enableCaptcha>false</enableCaptcha>
  </securityRealm>
  <disableRememberMe>false</disableRememberMe>
  <projectNamingStrategy class="jenkins.model.ProjectNamingStrategy$DefaultProjectNamingStrategy"/>
  <workspaceDir>${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULL_NAME}</workspaceDir>
  <buildsDir>${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/builds</buildsDir>
  <markupFormatter class="hudson.markup.EscapedMarkupFormatter"/>
  <jdks/>
  <viewsTabBar class="hudson.views.DefaultViewsTabBar"/>
  <myViewsTabBar class="hudson.views.DefaultMyViewsTabBar"/>
  <clouds/>
  <scmCheckoutRetryCount>0</scmCheckoutRetryCount>
  <views>
    <hudson.model.AllView>
      <owner class="hudson" reference="../../.."/>
      <name>all</name>
      <filterExecutors>false</filterExecutors>
      <filterQueue>false</filterQueue>
      <properties class="hudson.model.View$PropertyList"/>
    </hudson.model.AllView>
  </views>
  <primaryView>all</primaryView>
  <slaveAgentPort>-1</slaveAgentPort>
  <label></label>
  <crumbIssuer class="hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer">
    <excludeClientIPFromCrumb>false</excludeClientIPFromCrumb>
  </crumbIssuer>
  <nodeProperties/>
  <globalNodeProperties/>
</hudson>
```